# Reading a text file full with null characters and texts using fread

Tags: c, linux, file, filesystems, fread

I am trying to design a small file system.
I have created a text file to store the files data in.

```
int kufs_create_disk(char* disk_name, int disk_size){

    FILE* file_ptr = fopen(disk_name, "w");
    if (file_ptr == NULL) 
        return  -1;
    fseek (file_ptr, disk_size * 1024-1, SEEK_SET); 
    fwrite("", 1, sizeof(char), file_ptr); // to make a size for the file 
    fclose(file_ptr);
    DiskName=disk_name;
    return 0;
}
```

After writing to the file I get a file with the size I determine when I call the function.

```
 kufs_create_disk("test.txt", 5);
```

which creates a file with size of 5kbs with `'\0'` to fill this file to the size. 
I have created another function to write to this file in different places of the file which works just fine and I won't paste the code for simplicity. 
When I try to read from the file using `fread()`, I'm not getting all the data I have written into the memory; rather I get just some of the data.

My read implementation would be:

```
int kufs_read(int fd, void* buf, int n){    
    FILE *file_ptr= fopen("test.txt","a+");
    fseek (file_ptr, FAT[fd].position, SEEK_SET); //where FAT[fd].position is where I want to start my read and fd is for indexing purposes 
    fread(buf, 1, n, file_ptr); //n is the number of bytes to be read
    FAT[fd].position = FAT[fd].position + n;
}
```

The thing is the file reads some of the characters written and doesn't read the rest.  I did a little test by looping all over the file and checking whether every thing is being read and `fread` reads every thing but in the buf I only get some of the characters I've written.

The text file looks something like this:

```
0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00written string1written string2 0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00writtenstring 3 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

I get writtenstring1 and writtenstring2 in the buffer but I don't get writtenstring 3 for example.

Can you explain why?

Comment: As a terminological issue, text files don’t contain null bytes — unless the text is in an encoding such as UTF-16, whereupon bytes are no longer relevant at all.

Comment: *"i won't paste the code for simplicity"* Ok, but the code that you *did* post doesn't have the problem that you describe. Or at least there are too many missing pieces to be able to duplicate the problem. Which is why questions seeking debugging help (**why isn't this code working?**) must include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my question is does /00 affect the reading process of string charachters such as written string3 ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you please clarify more ? i might be a beginner just yet

Comment: It's a question of terminology — not of functionality, especially since you are working on Linux (if it were Windows, there'd be more to discuss).  Text files don't contain null bytes.  If you call your file laden with null bytes a 'text file', that is, by most standards, a misnomer — it is a binary file and not a text file.  However, as I said, it is a terminological problem, not an implementation problem.

Comment: Without an MCVE with global variable `DiskName` and the data structure (array of structures, but what's in the structure?) `FAT` defined and initialized, it is nigh on impossible for us to guess what's going wrong.  You don't error check your calls to `fseek()` or `fread()`; you don't know if they're working.  You've not echoed the results; that's a basic technique for diagnosing troubloe.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It needn't be very much more code than you've shown, but it does need to be more code than you've shown.

Comment: Incidentally, in the sample file contents, is the output like `0\00\0` meant to represent 4 bytes, a digit `'0'` (ASCII 48) and a null byte `'\0'` (ASCII 0) repeated?  Or is it something else?  There are various hex dump programs that can be used to represent such data unambiguously.

Comment: So the thing is i didn't want to post to much code and make my question understandable the FAT data structure is a an array of structs that i store the files data in (file name,position,blocks allocated ...)
and every '/0' represents a byte in my binary file

Comment: You should do something with all return values from system calls. Check that they are what you expect. What does `fread` return, for example?

Comment: i checked it by looping for mostly the size of the file it's returning 1 for all the file meaning it's reading everything but not displaying it all